# How can I see if this circuit would work on a breadboard?

Tags: led, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit

I have drawn a circuit but I am not sure how I can make it work if I will have to build it on a breadboard. Is there any breadboard simulator type of thing? [image: This is a photo of the circuit. Now I have to implement it]

Comment: http://fritzing.org/home/ -- Try this

Comment: but unfortunately off the topic question here.

Comment: What do you think it will do? I suspect it will just turn on both LED's continuously. Are you hoping it will blink them on and off in alternating fashion?

Comment: @MITURAJ surely you can recommend a better circuit sim than that?

Comment: @Andyaka yea. But not sure if he's looking for Breadboard simulator or circuit simulator o.O

Comment: Circuit sim of my choice (because it beats the pants off LTSpice is micro-cap (free student version).

Comment: When I was learning electronics simulators and good breadboards did not exist. Build the $@*% thing and learn more than you ever would with  a simulator.

Comment: @Andyaka In what way(s) does Circuit sim leave LTspice pants-less?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany maybe a misinterpretation of what I said. I'll be clear... micro-cap beats the pants off LTSpice. I suppose starting the sentance with the words "Circuit sim" is a bit misleading LOL.

Comment: Okay...my bad. but the pants question still is hanging in the air.. is it faster, more accurate, easier to add models, less ugly (wouldn't be hard!) or what?

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate circuits with LTspice.
http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html?domain=www.linear.com

If you are just looking to view what a circuit will do or to play with a more interactive simulation I recommend the following website.
http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html